# Sorting a double value of an object within an arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, double

I'm trying to sort my custom class chromosome by the value of their score attribute which is a double. These chromosomes are stored within an ArrayList. I know I have to use a comparator but I've read so many differing opinions online in the last hour that I'm utterly confused.

Attached is my code, if someone could point me in the right direction I would be much appreciated.

```
public class Chromosome
{

    public Gene[] genes;
    public double score;

    public Chromosome(int l)
    {
        genes = new Gene[l]; 
    }

    public int getLength()
    {
        return genes.length;
    }

    public void printChromo()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<this.genes.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(""+this.genes[i].teacher+","+
                this.genes[i].lecture+","+
                this.genes[i].room+","+
                this.genes[i].time+"");
        }   
    }

    public void setScore(double score)
    {
        this.score=score;
    }

    public double getScore()
    {
        return this.score;
    }
}
```

Don't know this make a difference but the score can only be a double between and including 0.0 to 1.0

Comment: found this question while google "java double sort" for my genetic alghorithm

Answer (score 79, accepted):

To use a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<Chromosome>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Chromosome c1, Chromosome c2) {
        return Double.compare(c1.getScore(), c2.getScore());
    }
});
```

If you plan on sorting numerous `List`s in this way I would suggest having `Chromosome` implement the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface (in which case you could simply call `Collections.sort(myList)`, without the need of specifying an explicit `Comparator`).

Comment: How would I get it an ascending list?

Comment: @Melo1991 There is a [`Collections.reverse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)) method if that's what you're after.

Comment: Or just c2.compareTo(c1) instead of c1.compareTo(c2).

Comment: I did not know about `Double.compare`. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

With **Java SE8** you could use lambda expression like so:

```
list.sort((o1, o2) -> Double.compare(o2.doubleField, o1.doubleField));
```

Answer (score 3):

I would implement the interface [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

```
public class Chromosome implements Comparable<Chromosome>{

    private double score;

    public Chromosome(double score){
        this.score = score;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Chromosome o) {
        return new Double(score).compareTo( o.score);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(score);
    }
}
```

Note that i moved score inside the Class..

Now you can use any [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) that is Sorted (like a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html))

If you insist on using the Arraylist you can use:

```
ArrayList<Chromosome> out = new ArrayList<Chromosome>();
out.add(new Chromosome(20));
out.add(new Chromosome(15));
System.out.println(out);
Collections.sort(out);
System.out.println(out);
```

Result:

```
[0.2, 0.15]
[0.15, 0.2]
```

Comment: When using this and I want to sort the arrayList I call the collections.sortmethod yes? Could you please tell me how to do that? @Frank

Comment: Or if you do not want to implement the `Comparable` interface, you can use the `Collections.sort( List<T>, Comparator<? super T> )` method

Comment: I've tried using this code @Frank and it still won't sort it :-(

Comment: I added a proof of concept, note that i also refined the compareTo method.

Comment: See the input in the Chromosome constructor is setting the amount of genes of the chromosome. Score is the fitness function score of the variables within the genes. I want to sort my list to have the best scores at the top and the worst at the bottom. It's not doing that, im just so confused here!

Comment: If you need sorting the other way around you just use: return new Double(o.score).compareTo(o);

Answer (score 3):

Why not use a [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) with a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) like this:

```
// your code
PriorityQueue<Chromosome> entries = new PriorityQueue<Chromosome>(1, new Comparator<Chromosome> () {
    @Override
    public int compare(Chromosome arg0, Chromosome arg1) {
        return (Double)(arg1.getScore()).compareTo((Double)arg0.getScore());
    }
});
entries.addAll(arrayListOfChromosomes);
// your code
```

The priority queue will then keep your data structure in sorted order.

Comment: Would I have this piece of code within my main class where I create my actual arrayList?

Comment: You could, or instead of the entire ArrayList, you call .add on every Chromosome.

Answer (score 3):

Since java 8 you can sort list of Double elements  very simple.

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(Chromosome::getScore));
```

or

```
Collections.sort(list, omparator.comparingDouble(Chromosome::getScore));
```

If you wanna get sorted list but you don't want to change your beginning list you can do it as following:

```
List<Chromosome> sortedList = list.stream()
     .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(A::getScore))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```